How do satellite trackers work when showing a "satellite"?
There are multiple sat trackers online where you can follow spacecraft orbiting Earth such as the ISS or the HST. I wonder how those trackers actually work when showing something near Earth, as the tracker must know that the object in question actually orbits the Earth, i.e. that it's a satellite. So how do those satellite trackers actually work?

Do they just show about any object above a certain altitude (e.g. 80, 100 or 120 km), regardless of whether it's on an orbital, suborbital or escape trajectory? If so, does it also show natural objects such as flying-by meteoroids or the two temporary moons Earth had when they were in Earth's orbit?
Or do satellite trackers show any object beyond a minimum speed, e.g. 7.5 km/s (4.7 mi/s) or faster. If so, a minimum speed would need to count at a specific altitude only, as the necessary orbital speed gets lower the higher you go until no ground speed at all in geostationary orbit. If there's a speed limit, would the SpaceX Starship (which didn't reach full orbital speed) have already been shown on a satellite tracker?
And then I wonder how far away from Earth satellite trackers work. Is there an altitude/distance limit such as geosynchronous altitude (35800 km) or 1.5 million km (edge of Earth's hill sphere, L1 and L2) or a random number like 250 thousand km or miles?
I also wonder if there's an upper speed limit so to exclude objects at escape velocity. Again, this would need to be altitude-dependent.


Most tracking websites are probably not showing live tracking information. They get the orbit information periodically from some agency which actually own antennas and radars. the websites then show the predicted data for the current time. So the criteria for listing might be "what the database from X agency contains".

Do you have a specific tracking website in mind? If you tell us which site, we might be able to find out where they get their info.

@Hobbes For example this one: https://www.n2yo.com/?s=60202 or this one: https://satellitemap.space/ or this one: https://www.orbtrack.org/#/?satName=STARLINK-2024 or this one: https://in-the-sky.org/satmap_worldmap.php

e.g. N2YO says "mainly space surveillance data provided by "Space Track", ... a partial catalog of observations collected by the US Space Surveillance Network, operated by US Air Force Space Command (AFSPC) ... n2yo.com is an authorized redistributor and the license is renewed annually ... In special circumstances ... derived from public sources"

We know the location of GPS satellites because they transmit it. I wonder why other satellites don't do the same - they must certainly all be equipped with a transmitter and a camera doesn't need to be sophisticated to track a couple of stars. Coding that - considering it's not mission-critical - should also be inexpensive.

@Vorac that's not quite a good way to characterize the situation. They certainly do transmit their own ephemeris and a constellation almanac, but that is uploaded to the satellites from ground stations after the GPS ground infrastructure determines their positions and predicts their future trajectories (which is what ephemerides are). There are no cameras - those would certainly be useless for precisions of centimeters (I didn't say accuracy).


How do satellite trackers work when showing a "satellite"?

Satellite "tracking" websites do not "track" anything.
You could blow up the satellite, and that little dot would continue to move around the Earth for days or weeks, depending on the situation.
They extrapolate the orbits from data that's posted on other sites, and that is on the average a day old or more.
Let's take the ny2o link from your comment.

https://www.n2yo.com/?s=60202


Click the satellite name in the top right. This takes you to a page with more information about that object.

At the bottom is the Two Line Element Set probably from Celestrak or similar site. Some folks from the government/military do the actual tracking of satellites, using mostly radar and some optical data from satellite tracking telescopes, and perhaps other data. They do some fitting to the trajectory using computer programs, and then predict where the satellite will go in the next few days.
Then they take those predictions, and approximate and squeeze them down into these tiny TLEs.
Websites like this then use a program that implements SGP4  and it's SGP4 that generates the predicted apprximate motion that you see plotted on these websites.
If we look at the TLE, we see 24195.58334491 in the first line. The first two digits 24 are the year and the rest 195.58334491 is the decimal day of the "epoch" of the TLE - meaning the time when it is most accurate, which is probably fairly close to the time it was calculated (but not necessarily)
From this answer to my StackOverflow question we can convert that to a time:

That's July 13, 2024, at 14:00:01.224 UTC.
If you are viewing the page after that time, you're simply seeing a prediction or extrapolation, called a "propagator". It's not tracking, but "LIVE REAL TIME SATELLITE TRACKING" certainly sounds cool! :-)


Note: I'll point folks back up to the comments under the question and to the other answer(s), both of  which contain a wealth of additional informative information.

(see also "...a wealth of additional informative information." looks somehow wrong to me - redundant to call information informative or OK? Missing comma?)

None of the current services show actual 'live' data.
This is due to physics which mean achieving global coverage of LEO would require a site looking DOWN from high orbit.
Rather we have a multitude of organizations operating radar and optical detection systems and feeding into various data pools, normally in return for money*.
This data is then filtered and compared to remove duplicates and make decisions about short term or maneuvering objects - eg showing a 24 hour old third party sighting or that published by the owner as their intentions. See Uhoh's answer.
Each of these services will have their own limits - Radar sites are mostly fixed phased arrays that provide highly accurate data for objects in the beams but cannot change facing. Pointing radars can track any object in sight of the station, but normally only one at a time. Optical systems need sunlight and work best at confirming known objects are still in a previously predicted position, but can scale well and be done by interested individuals
This means that 'live' websites are always showing predicted positions, though for some websites some objects may have close to live update (eg websites showing an organizations own vehicles). SpaceX claims to update space-track.org starlink TLE data three times a day.
In terms of coverage, there will be no hard edges. There are claims that objects smaller than 10cm across are tracked by some radar systems in LEO, going further out objects need to be larger to be tracked, or be actively co-operating (radio transponder or LASER retroreflector).
Actual live tracking data would be not that interesting to watch, being fairly noisy 'slots' of coverage and mostly just showing previously tracked vehicles in their predicted positions.
*Some government organizations provide free TLE information, but manipulate the data to obfuscate detection capabilities and their own space activities.

There's a few other methods. Active optical systems utilize laser ranging from retroreflectors on satellites, that's used on GNSS (GPS) and scientific satellites which need extremely precise orbital determination (this is mentioned in your optical link). LEO sats, such as Starlink, the ISS and various cubesats, utilize GNSS receivers and downlink their position, that provides on-demand data without paying anybody.
